# Complex argument imaginary number

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone clarify this for me?

Wolfram:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg%28i%5Ei%29

But as per my derivation:
$[i^i]=[e^{iln(i)}] =  i\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k$, since $ln(i) = i\frac{\pi}{2}$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, $\ln(i)=i\frac \pi 2$.  When you multiply that by $i$, as you show in $e^{i\ln(i)}$, you get $-\frac \pi 2$.  Then you add in the $2\pi k$ just fine.

Comment: since $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$, $\theta = ln(i) = i\frac{\pi}{2}$ so that means the argument is $ i\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi$. right?

Comment: That is right for the argument of $i$, but you had (correctly) a factor of $i$ multiplying that.  The exponent of $e$ is $i \ln(i)$ in your post.

Answer (score 1):

$$
i^i = e^{i\log i} = e^{i(\ln1 + i\arg i)} = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$

Comment: so how do i then find the argument from this derivation of $i^i$?

Comment: @rebc this is a positive real number so the argument is $0$

Answer (score 1):

You only found $\log i$, not $i^i$.